# Making code loop until multiple parameters successful

Tags: c#, while-loop

Have the following stretch of code:

```
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out inValue))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid gender");
                Console.WriteLine("Please, insert a valid gender");
            }
```

Not only do I want it to loop until int.TryParse is successful (what it does now), I also want it to loop until inValue == 1 || inValue == 2. Simply adding that to the while statement throws up errors.

Comment: How exactly does your while look?

Comment: @Sayse, 

while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out inValue),  inValue==1 || inValue==2) shows the following:

Parenthesis needed after inValue in "inValue==1"

Two semicolons needed after last parenthesis

Last parenthesis is "invalid expression term  ')'

"Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement" for both inValue== statements.

Comment: You are separating with a "," afther the  try parse that wont work

Comment: The comma after the TryParse is incorrect, the comma normally separates parameters, a while loop only takes in the 1 parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the other condition like this:

```
int inValue;
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out inValue) && (inValue == 1 || inValue ==2))
{
    Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid gender");
    Console.WriteLine("Please, insert a valid gender");
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems I was writing the additional conditions incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

> Not only do I want it to loop until int.TryParse is successful (what
>   it does now), I also want it to loop until inValue == 1 || inValue ==
>   2.

You need the `!` operator over both the condition parts to loop the input until *1* or *2* is entered. Otherwise loop will break even any int number is entered.

```
int inValue;
while (!(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out inValue) && (inValue == 1 || inValue ==2)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid gender");
    Console.WriteLine("Please, insert a valid gender");
}
```

Note: The following loop will break for any int number entered.

```
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out inValue) && (inValue == 1 || inValue ==2))
{
    Console.WriteLine("That is not a valid gender");
    Console.WriteLine("Please, insert a valid gender");
}
```